# If $f$ is bounded and measurable and $f^2$ is Lebesgue integrable, is $f$ is Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a bounded function with the property  that $f$ is measurable and $f^2$ is Lebesgue integrable. Is $f$ is Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Also, are you sure you've stated the problem correctly? As written, the fact that $f^2$ is integrable is irrelevant.

Comment: But if you change Lebesgue integrable by Riemann integrable, then you can take a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244409/if-f2-is-riemann-integrable-is-f-always-riemann-integrable

Comment: Perhaps you don't want "bounded" there. In that case, see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273263/showing-l20-1-is-contained-in-l10-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded and measurable, it's integrable.  Since $f$ is bounded, $\|f\|_{\infty} < \infty$.  So $\displaystyle \int_a^b |f(x)| dx \le \int_a^b \|f\|_{\infty} dx = (b-a) \|f\|_{\infty} < \infty$.